# Regarding the graph of $y = k^{2} x$

Tags: error-analysis

If I plot the graph of $y = k^{2} x$, I believe finding $k$ using the gradient of the graph and then squaring it will give me the gradient. But I'm not sure what I'm doing is right. Is there another method to find the gradient of the graph?

EDIT: For example, if I plot the graph of $y=k^{2}x$ using some data and the graphing software (Logger Pro) generates the gradient value as 3.14. So will that be my $k^{2}$ value or do I have to square the value of $k$ obtained to get the gradient?

Comment: Just cross check your result by calculating point using the result. Usually one performs a linear regression. However, if you are interested in that this is not the correct site. Please read about it and ask questions on http://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Where's the physics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Geometrically**

Try to plot

$$y=3x$$

Moving one step out along $x$ adds 3 to $y$. Moving one more $x$ step adds 3 more to $y$. We say that *the gradient* or *the slope* of this graph is 3. Your plotting software will tell you that the gradient is 3 as well.

Then try to plot

$$y=10x$$

Again, 10 is the gradient. Your plotting software will tell you that. Now plot

$$y=k^2x$$

Naturally, to keep the pattern, $k^2$ is the gradient. Not $k$ but $k^2$. So the squaring is already included. If your plotting software in some specific case measures the gradient to be $3.14$, then this means that $k^2=3.14$.

**Mathematically**

Finding the gradient from a linear expression is a simple differentiation:

$$\text{gradient} =\frac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm dx} =\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \left(k^2x\right)=k^2$$

Again we see that the gradient, the *derivative* of a first-order polynomial, which is a linear function, is $k^2$ and thus includes the squaring.

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure what you are after. The gradient is defined as the slope at a specific point $p \in \mathbb R^n$ of a function $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$.

$\begin{equation}
\text{grad}(f) = \nabla f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n \\
\nabla f(p) = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial f(p)}{\partial x_1}\cr\frac{\partial f(p)}{\partial x_2}\cr \vdots\cr\frac{\partial f(p)}{\partial x_n}\cr\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}$

In your case this would be given by the total derivative since your function depends on the one dimensional variable $x$:

$\begin{equation}
\text{grad}(y)=\frac{\text{d}y}{\text {d}x}= k^2
\end{equation}
$

So there is no need for squaring the value you obtain.

Comment: Oh.. okay so let's say for example, I plot the graph of $y = k^{2} x$ using some data and the graphing software (Logger Pro) generates the gradient value as 3.14. So will that be my $k^2$ value or do I have to square it? That's what I was wondering.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Logger Pro. However following the usual definition of the gradient, it should be your $k^2$.

Comment: Read [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope) or as much as you need to understand it.